# Proof of a property on convex and $\beta$-smooth functions

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am using [a set of popular online notes on convex optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4980.pdf). A function is $\beta$-smooth if its gradient is $\beta$-Lipschitz. Can anyone help me with the following line in the proof:

[image]

How does one justify combining the two terms:

$\int\limits_{0}^t \nabla f(y+t(x-y))^T(x-y)dt$ and $\nabla f(y)^T(x-y)$ together?

It seems to me you need to do the following:

$\int\limits_{0}^t \nabla f(y+t(x-y))^T(x-y)dt - \nabla f(y)^T(x-y)$ = $\int\limits_{0}^t \nabla f(y+t(x-y))^T(x-y)dt - \frac{1}{t}\int\limits_{0}^t \nabla f(y)^T(x-y) dt$ =

$\int\limits_{0}^t \nabla f(y+t(x-y))^T(x-y) - \frac{1}{t} \nabla f(y)^T(x-y) dt$

= $\int\limits_{0}^t (\nabla f(y+t(x-y)) - \frac{1}{t} \nabla f(y))^T(x-y) dt$

But no such $\frac{1}{t}$ term is used in the derivation. Can someone check?

(Assume that $dt$ in the integral is a dummy variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the [upper limit](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfDefiniteIntegral.aspx) of the definite integral $\int_0^t \nabla f(y+t(x-y))^\intercal(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}t$ is *fixed* at $t = 1$, so that $\nabla f(y)^\intercal(x-y)$ enters into the definite integral $\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}t$ without any change.  This gives
\begin{split}
& \left| \int_0^1 \nabla f(y+t(x-y))^\intercal (x-y) \,\mathrm{d}t
- \nabla f(y)^\intercal (x-y) \right| \\
&= \left |
\int_0^1 [ \nabla f(y+t(x-y)) - \nabla f(y) ]^\intercal (x-y) \,\mathrm{d}t \right| \\
&\le \int_0^1 | [ \nabla f(y+t(x-y)) - \nabla f(y) ]^\intercal (x-y) | \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&\le \int_0^1 \lVert \nabla f(y+t(x-y)) - \nabla f(y) \rVert \cdot \lVert x - y \rVert \,\mathrm{d}t \quad \mbox{(Cauchy--Schwartz)}\\
&\le \int_0^1 \beta \lVert t(x - y) \rVert \cdot \lVert x - y \rVert \,\mathrm{d}t \quad (f \text{ is } \beta \text{-smooth}) \\
&= \int_0^1 \beta t \lVert x - y \rVert^2 \,\mathrm{d}t
\end{split}

Comment: I see. My mind played a trick on me